# "Each and every one of you's opinions"

Tags: grammar, sentence

Suppose a group of friends are having a discussion and the turn comes to one of the friends who says the below sentence.

"I respect each and every one of you's opinions"

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

If it is, then is even "Each and every one of you's *opinion* also correct?

Comment: "Your" is the possessive form of "you".

Comment: @HotLicks - It’s not “Each and every one o’ y’all’s”?

Comment: *Each and every one of you* is a syntactic constituent, just like *someone else* or the *the Queen of England* or *that guy at the door* is. As such, what’s happening here is that the possessive clitic is attaching to the end of that constituent. This can make for awkward phrasings that are probably better avoided in formal situations lest the guy at the door's wife should become angry with your grammar. See the linked duplicate. And no, the door has no wife.

Comment: It's better to say that you respect the opinion of each and every one of you. That way the door man's wife won't get all upset with you.

Comment: That cleared things up.  :)

Comment: I won't offend the wife of the guy at the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I respect each and every one of you's opinions*" is NOT grammatically correct.  It should be "I respect each and every one of **your** opinions". Or, I respect everybody's opinions.

from [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc)

> **Pronouns: possessive (my, mine, your, yours, etc.)**
>
> We use pronouns to refer to possession and ‘belonging’. There are two
> types: ***possessive pronouns*** and ***possessive determiners.*** We use
> possessive determiners before a noun. We use possessive pronouns in
> place of a noun:
>
> *Is that [determiner]**your** scarf?*
>
> *It’s very similar to [pronoun]**mine***. (It’s very similar to my scarf.)
>
> *That’s not [determiner]**their** house.* [pronoun]**Theirs** has got a red front door.
>
> *It was [determiner]**his** fault not [pronoun]**hers**.*

**Typical errors**:

> *We don’t use **’s** after possessive pronouns:*
>
> Are those gloves hers?
>
> **Not:** Are those gloves her’s?
>
> **’s** is not used with the possessive pronoun **its**. ***It’s means ‘it is’:***
>
> The team is proud of its ability to perform consistently well.
>
> **Not**: … proud of it’s ability …
>
> ***We don’t use another determiner with a possessive determiner:***
>
> I’m going to get my hair cut this afternoon.
>
> **Not**: … get **the my** hair cut …
>
> ***We don’t use possessive determiners on their own. They are always at the beginning of noun phrases:***
>
> *That’s not my book. It’s yours. (or It’s your book.)*
>
> **Not:** It’s your.
>
> ***We don’t use possessive pronouns before nouns:***
>
> *Lots of our friends were at the party.*
>
> **Not**: Lots of ours friends …

Comment: Does the Queen of England's hat belong to England or to the Queen? Or does England's hat now have a queen?

Comment: The Queen belongs to England and the hat belongs to the Queen! The Queen of England's daughter's hat = The hat of the daughter of the Queen of England.

Comment: Certainly the hat belongs to the Queen, but I don't think that you can say that the Queen belongs to England; perhaps in former times the other way around, though, when England belonged to its Queen.

Comment: Can we say, the British Queen and the British Queen's hat?

Comment: Yes. But people do not belong to countries in English. :)

Comment: Yes, people do not belong to countries. But Kings/Queens/PMs/Presidents can belong to countries, can't they?

Answer (score 0):

You's or yous is the **not standard** plural of *you*. It is not part of the American or British common Dictionary. Therefore, outside of informal conversations it isn't considered valid English.

Sources: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yous), [this painstakingly explained answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107320/how-common-is-the-usage-of-yous-as-a-plural-of-you).

Comment: He wasn't using it as a plural.  He was using it as a possessive.  (But of course it's wrong for that as well.)

Comment: It isn't the possessive of *you*. It’s the possessive of the entire "each and every one of you".

Comment: Like `vous` in french